# What does a gcc output file look like and what exactly does it contain?

Tags: gcc, object-files

While compiling a c file, gcc by default compiles it to a file called "a.out". My professor said that the output file contains the binaries, but I when I open it I usually encounter unreadable text (VS Code says something like "This file contains unsupported text encoding").
I assumed that by 'binaries', I would be able to see literal zeroes and ones in the file but that does not seem to be the case. So what exactly does it output file look like or what exactly does it contain and what is 'text encoding'? Why can I not *read* it? What special characters might it contain? I'm aware of the fact that gcc first pre-processes, which means it removes all comments, expands all macros and copies the contents of any header files that might be included. You get the header file by running `gcc -E <file_name>.c`, then the this processed file is complied into assembly. Up to this point, the output files are readable, i.e., I can open them with VS Code, but after this the assembled code and the object file thereafter are *human-unreadable*.
 
For reference, I have no prior experience with programming or any language for that matter and this is my first CS related course in my first sem of college, and I apologize if this is too trivial of a question to ask.

Comment: This is not meant to be site to _learn_ programming, rather it's a site for people that know programming to ask programming related question. Ask your professor and clear any uncertainties with him, or hire a tutor to introduce you to the programming. As for you question, it's too broad - see [ask]. `what exactly does it output file look like` like zeros and ones `what exactly does it contain` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format `what is 'text encoding'` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Comment: `Why can I not read it?` Because the program you are using to read it does not suport reading it. `What special characters might it contain?` Any or none, depends on how you define the term "special character". The file contains any _bytes_.

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you for informing me, I didn't know that. Thanks for the links as well. I'll try to refrain from asking something like that in the future. The only reason I asked here was that I couldn't find a satisfactory answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had the same confusion early on. Not about that file type specifically, but about binary vs text files.

After all aren't all files, even text ones binary? In the sense that all information is `1`s and `0`s? Well, yes, all information can be stored/transmitted as `1`s and `0`s, but that's not what binary/text files refer to.

It refers to what that information, the content of the file, those `1`s and `0`s represent.

In a text file the bytes encode characters. In a binary file the bits encode some information that is not text. The format and semantics of that information  is completely free, it can mean anything and use whatever encoding scheme. It's up to the application that writes/reads the file to properly understand the bit patterns.

Most text editors (like VS Code) when open a file they treat it as a text file. I.e. they try to interpret the bit patterns as a text encoding scheme (e.g. ASCII or UTF-8) But not all bit patterns are valid ASCII/UTF-8 so that's why you get "unsupported text encoding".

If you want to inspect the actual `1`s and `0` for both text and binary files you need to use a utility that shows you that, e.g. hex viewers/editors.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply! I appreciate the help. I understand now. So what I infer from your reply, there might some random string of characters in that 'binary' file that VS Code interprets as some ASCII value. It's almost like there's a seemingly random string of alphabets which one might try to interpret as English words/phrases when they actually are in German.

Comment: Yes. Something like that. GCC outputs an executable for Linux. Executables for Linux are in a very specific format. It's called ELF. If you are curious you can search for Linux elf format. And yes, the name is from LOTR 

Comment: " there might some random string of characters in that 'binary' file" no. The text editor tries to interpret all bits, from the start of the file until the end (or until it decides to give up). Those bits represent some binary data, but the text editor doesn't know that and tries to interpret them as text.

Comment: Get a hex viewer and inspect some text and binary files with it. You will understand better.

Comment: yes I opened it in an online hex viewer I found. Thanks for your help again.